# Cloning Credit/debit card chip

Tags: credit-card, smartcard

I have a nice, expensive, metal credit card with a chip but it's from an older card. I’m wanting to rewrite the magnetic stripe and the chip to my new card. I know how to rewrite the magnetic stripe but what do I need to buy and do, to rewrite the chip?

Comment: The point of the chip is to make it impossible to do what you want to do.

Comment: Probably something like physically destroying the card using acid etching to gain direct access to the microprocessor, then trying to reverse-engineer it.  These chips are designed to prevent exactly what you propose.  With physical access, it's still possible of course, just very expensive, and likely requires a degree in EE, expensive equipment, and MANY hours.  I have a suspicion you're just trying to commit fraud, however.

Comment: ...If you only care about contact (+ stripe) you might be able to transfer the physical chip itself, since all of the hardware [appears to lie under the contact pad](https://www.christinedemerchant.com/dissecting-chip-card.html). If you have a contactless card, you might be out of luck, since the antenna might be embedded into the rest of the card.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases I've seen (both working at a bank, and owning a bunch of credit cards), when the bank issued you your new card the old card was either immediately blocked, or set to expire (AKA be blocked) 30-90 days in the future. As a result, the magstripe and chip contained in the old card will soon be non-functional, assuming they are not already. I would recommend simply using the new card mailed to you by your bank, and not landing yourself on any watchlists by purchasing the expensive equipment required to attempt what you're looking to do.

Plus, depending on the bank, when you mess up and render the new card useless, they may take great pleasure in charging you a new card fee to allow you the *privilege* of continuing to access your accounts with them.